# trying to compile vlc for iphone5 (ios6 , armv7 armv7s, iphoneos6.0) , got this error

Tags: xcode, ios6, vlc, libvlc

> Ld
>   build/MobileVLC.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLC.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/VLC
>   normal armv7s
>       cd /Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/looneydoodle/.rbenv/shims:/Users/looneydoodle/.rbenv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   -arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/build/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/External/MobileVLCKit -L/Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/External/MediaLibraryKit -F/Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/build/Release-iphoneos -filelist /Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/build/MobileVLC.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLC.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/VLC.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -Wl,-no_pie -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework
>   OpenGLES -framework AudioToolbox -framework QuartzCore -liconv -lz
>   /Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/VLCKit/build/Release-iphoneos/libMobileVLCKit.a
>   /Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/MediaLibraryKit/build/Release-iphoneos/libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a
>   -lsqlite3 -lstdc++.6 -lbz2 -lxml2 -framework CoreData -framework CoreText -framework MediaPlayer -o
>   /Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/build/MobileVLC.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLC.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/VLC
>   ld: warning: ignoring file
>   /Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/VLCKit/build/Release-iphoneos/libMobileVLCKit.a,
>   file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked
>   (armv7s):
>   /Users/looneydoodle/projects/MobileVLC/ImportedSources/VLCKit/build/Release-iphoneos/libMobileVLCKit.a
>   Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
>   "_VLCMediaTracksInformationType", referenced from:
>         -[MLParsingOperation mediaDidFinishParsing:] in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o)
>   "_VLCMediaTracksInformationVideoWidth", referenced from:
>         -[MLParsingOperation mediaDidFinishParsing:] in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o)
>   "_VLCMediaTracksInformationVideoHeight", referenced from:
>         -[MLParsingOperation mediaDidFinishParsing:] in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCMedia", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLThumbnailerQueue.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCMediaPlayer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieViewController.o   "_VLCMediaTracksInformationAudioChannelsNumber", referenced from:
>         -[MLParsingOperation mediaDidFinishParsing:] in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o)
>   "_VLCMediaTracksInformationAudioRate", referenced from:
>         -[MLParsingOperation mediaDidFinishParsing:] in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o)
>   "_VLCMediaTracksInformationTypeAudio", referenced from:
>         -[MLParsingOperation mediaDidFinishParsing:] in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCMediaThumbnailer", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLThumbnailerQueue.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCTime", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieGridViewCell.o
>         objc-class-ref in MVLCMovieTableViewCell.o   "_VLCMediaTracksInformationTypeVideo", referenced from:
>         -[MLParsingOperation mediaDidFinishParsing:] in libMobileMediaLibraryKit.a(MLFileParserQueue.o) ld: symbol(s) not
>   found for architecture armv7s collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  Ld
>   build/MobileVLC.build/Release-iphoneos/MobileVLC.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/VLC
>   normal armv7s (1 failure)

Any idea how to compile the MobileVLCKit to armv7 ?